# How to update MySQL column with thousands of data in PHP automatically using json data

Tags: php, mysql, json, loops

I have a "users" table with columns:

```
Id | user_id | name | ip_address | lat | lng | active
```

The latitude(lat) and longitude(lng) columns are empty, and I need to populate them with the approximate location (I do not need a precise location). Using this forum, in another question, I discovered that I would have to separate the IPs, and use a location library. Well. I created a function to extract the IP and added the IP2Location library to my project. It works if I take IP for IP, get latitude and longitude, and add one by one in MySQL, however, I have 125,000 records, and there is no way to do the job manually.
Would anyone know how to do this?

Using this function

```
function List_ip() {
    global $sqlConnect, $db;
    if ($db['loggedin'] == false) {
        return false;
    }

    $ips = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, "SELECT `user_id` , `ip_address` FROM " . T_USERS . " WHERE `active` = '1'");
    while ($fetched_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ips)) {
     $list_ip[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $fetched_data); 
    }    

   return $list_ip;

}
```

I have the following json result

```
{
     "api_status": 200,
     "ips": [
         {
             "user_id": "1",
             "ip_address": "177.198.86.7x"
         },
         {
             "user_id": "21",
             "ip_address": "177.18.246.9x"
         },
         {
             "user_id": "52",
             "ip_address": "177.36.60.1x"
         }
     ]
}
```

I have this script that can give me latitude and longitude based on IP

```
<?php
require_once './assets/libraries/vendor/ip2location/ip2location-php/IP2Location.php';

$reader = new \IP2Location\Database('./IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB9.BIN', \IP2Location\Database::FILE_IO);

$records = $reader->lookup('8.8.8.8', \IP2Location\Database::ALL);

echo '<pre>';
echo 'IP Number             : ' . $records['ipNumber'] . "\n";
echo 'Latitude              : ' . $records['latitude'] . "\n";
echo 'Longitude             : ' . $records['longitude'] . "\n";

?>
```

How to insert latitude and longitude data for each of the IPs automatically?

Sorry for the amount of code, I'm trying to be as clear as possible.

Comment: `utf8_encode` in the context of DB results? `utf8_encode` should ideally never be used. Do you know what it does?

Comment: You already have the ip addresses in your table, but you want to update the hole table to make it has the ip addresses with LAT & LNG for each row, is that right?

Comment: MAZux Yeahh, Exactly!

Comment: Dharman I use this to decode the ISO-8859-1 standard to the utf-8 standard. That way a certain Latin standard string can be used (my users are 90% of Latin America) in other parts of the application. In this API I will use the user name in the future, so that the name of the people using 'àáâääåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõøùùûûýýÿ does not become ( ) I will have to use this.
Is there any reason why I should not use it?

Comment: Instead of getting username and ip from database, just get the distinct IP addresses. then instead of adding to the array for each row... call your IP2Location function to get the values and then in the same loop write an update statement to update the table where ip is the ip you got.

Comment: Nawed Khan thanks for the support.
Do you have any examples of how to implement this? I have not been able to understand loops well yet (I have just over 1 month studying PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the function that gets the distinct (unique) IP addresses and pass them to second function to get Lat/Long and update database.

```
function List_ip() {
    global $sqlConnect, $db;
    if ($db['loggedin'] == false) {
        return false;
    }

    $ips = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, "SELECT DISTINCT `ip_address` FROM " . T_USERS . " WHERE `active` = '1'");
    while ($fetched_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ips)) {
       ip2LocationAndUpdate($fetched_data["ip_address"]); //passing to other function
    }
}
```

The global stuff

```
require_once './assets/libraries/vendor/ip2location/ip2location-php/IP2Location.php';
$reader = new \IP2Location\Database('./IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB9.BIN', \IP2Location\Database::FILE_IO);
```

The second function that does the IP2Location and update sql

```
function ip2LocationAndUpdate($ip_address){
    global $sqlConnect, $reader;
    $records = $reader->lookup($ip_address, \IP2Location\Database::ALL);

    $updateSQL = "UPDATE " . T_USERS . " SET `lat` = '$records["latitude"]', `lat` = '$records["latitude"]' WHERE `ip_address` = '$ip_address'";

    //execute the sql with mysqli or whatever you are using
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have too many rows to insert I would recommend to create a cron task to run in the background, its faster and does nor affect to your website (in case you have it)

Search crontab.
Or shell_exec

Then if you want to show a progress you can use broadcasting or pusher for example

Answer (score 0):

Nawed Khan's answer solved my problem with a few minor modifications.
This is my code currently running 100%.
Thanks to everyone for the answer, this was very useful to my learning the PHP language.

```
function List_ip() {
    global $sqlConnect, $db;
    if ($db['loggedin'] == false) {
        return false;
    }

    $ips = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, "SELECT DISTINCT `ip_address` FROM " . T_USERS . " WHERE `lat` = '0'");
    while ($fetched_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ips)) {
       ip2LocationAndUpdate($fetched_data["ip_address"]); //passing to other function
    }
}

 require_once 'assets/libraries/vendor/ip2location/ip2location-php/IP2Location.php';

 $reader = new \IP2Location\Database('IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB9.BIN', \IP2Location\Database::FILE_IO);

function ip2LocationAndUpdate($ip_address){
    global $sqlConnect, $reader;
    $records = $reader->lookup($ip_address, \IP2Location\Database::ALL);

     //execute the sql with mysqli or whatever you are using

    $latitu = $records['latitude'];
    $longitu = $records['longitude'];

    $updateSQL = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, "UPDATE " . T_USERS . " SET `lat` = '$latitu', `lng` = '$longitu' WHERE `ip_address` = '$ip_address'");


    return $updateSQL;


}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use flowing algorithm to solve your problem

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<125000;$i++)
{
 // here run what you want to do
}
?>
```

**Note**: after doing 1000 record stop for 10 second if you use server of online website

Comment: **FUTURE READERS**: DO NOT DO THIS! It is considered bad practice to run sql statements in a loop